# Python 3.8.9: Decompyle3 ModuleNotFoundError issue

Tags: python, decompiler

I downloaded Decompyle3 from 'https://github.com/rocky/python-decompile3'
And I used the command.

```
python setup.py install
```

Finally, I tried this command, but it was not working. i'd appreciate if you help me with this problem. Thanks.

```
    C:\WINDOWS\system32>decompyle3 MainEngine.pyc

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\82106\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\decompyle3-script.py", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('decompyle3==3.7.6.dev0', 'console_scripts', 'decompyle3')())
  File "C:\Users\82106\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\decompyle3-script.py", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
  File "C:\Users\82106\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\metadata.py", line 77, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "C:\Users\82106\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'decompyle3'
```

Comment: Why are you running in `C:\WINDOWS\system32`?  Are you doing this in an admin console?

Comment: There is no file called "decompyle3-script.py" in their repo.  How, exactly, did you install this?  Did you run it inside an IDE?